# Delete Messages with sockets

Tags: sockets, typescript

It actually should be pretty simple, but I can't seem to get a hang of it.
I want to create a chatroom with sockets.
I already managed it to send Messages, but I want to be able to delete them all.

The code for sending messages:

Server:

```
let io = socket(server);
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('chat', function (data) {
        io.sockets.emit('chat', data)
    });
}
```

Client:
    let socket = io.connect(window.location.protocol + '//' + 
    window.location.host);

```
socket.on('chat', function (data) {
    let output: JQuery = $('#output');
    let feedback: JQuery = $('#feedback');
    output.html(output.html() + '<p><strong>' + data.username + ':<br> 
    </strong>' + data.message + '</p>');
    feedback.html('');
});

function sendMessage() {
    let message: JQuery = $('#message');
    let username: JQuery = $('#username');
    let feedback: JQuery = $('#feedback');
    socket.emit('chat', {
        message: message.val(),
        username: username.val(),
        feedback: feedback.val(),        
    });
    message.html('');
}
$(function () {
    $('#send').on('click', function () {
        sendMessage();        
    });
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I already managed it to send Messages, but I want to be able to delete them all.

What do you mean by delete them? They are not stored on backend - it only broadcasting messages to clients.

**EDIT**

If you want user for just clear chat, according to code you provided - you can just clear **output**:

```
...
let output: JQuery = $('#output');
...
let someButton = $('#<SOME BUTTON ID>');
someButton.click(() => {
    output.html('');
});    
...
```

Comment: sorry, I haven't been clear. I want a button where the user can delete the chat, so that  the textfield is empty.

Comment: this works fine, thank you! but if I open chrome in two windows the messages only get deleted in the window where I click the button. When I change io.sockets.emit to socket.broadcast.emit  nothing works anymore

Comment: As I understand now - if any user click "delete" button - messages for all users should be deleted. For that case - you need to define new event (for example: "delete") and broadcast it to clients. On that event receiving -  just clear output same way as on button click.